# What are the security implications for storing access tokens outside of Meteor.js accounts?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm looking to build a Meteor.js app that will perform various tasks using social media APIs.

Different social media accounts need to be associated to different projects within the app rather that associated with one user. So it make sense to me to store the associated access tokens in the projects collection.

I'm just wondering if there any security implications of this approach as I can find any evidence of anyone attempting this?

Comment: you should use `settings.json` best way to handle that http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_settings

Answer (score 0):

OAuth tokens generally represent a single person, so I'd say it'd be a best practice to always associated with a single user. While you could tie a single token to a project (eg Coca Cola facebook media campaign), it's probably going to be troublesome down the road (have you considered multiple users on the same project? 1 user with more than 1 project?). I'm guessing each project is for a media campaign , and if so, each campaign should probably be a sub-entity of user.

For example,
what I'd suggest is a 1-to-1 relationship between OAuth token and user.
Then, each user has a property like `projects = []` where you can put the project IDs in the array as a foreign key. Then in the projects collection, each project would have at least 2 fields:

```
{
   tokenAPI: facebook
   token: 2039asfkljelkfajw
}
```

No security problems either way, just the possibility of saving some headaches.